# How to test a application which is having multiple recent screen?

Tags: manual-testing, test-design, android, quality-assurance

I am testing one application which has multiple recent screens for recent activity!

I am working for an email client android application which is having different different modules e.g. Email module, Calendar module, Document module etc. When I open modules one by one and press home key and then if I check the recent screen in android device I am able to see all the modules which I had open recently for the same application. If you check gmail or any other application then only 1 recent screen we can find.

How to write test cases or is it a good idea to have multiple recent screens for 1 android application?

Should I raise a question to the development team to have only one recent screen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prior to raising a question to the development team, you should refer to the software requirement and or software design documentation first, if any. Check in the requirement or design, how the application should behave related with the recent screen. Is there any purpose or objective in designing application with multiple recent screens? If it is not stated in the document, you could clarify it to your product owner to ensure the expected behavior.

In designing the test cases, you should know what the acceptance criteria of that functionality first. What are the expected or the correct behavior and vice versa? For instance, will the multiple recent screens display the same information or something else? My suggestion is to check your documentation first and if it's still unclear, try to escalate it to your product owner/client.

Hope this helps.